# AVPlayer seek M3U8

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using AVPlayer to play m3u8 from a server.

```
avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl]];
[avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[avPlayer play];
```

And i want the seek option will be work too, so i :

```
CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(new, 1);
[avPlayer seekToTime:time];
```

And i have a problem that the seek work only for Forward and not for Backwards.
Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Use this `[avPlayer setCurrentTime:time];` then do `[avPlayer play]`

Comment: avplayer not have setCurrentTime function

Comment: Sorry i thought it was AVAudioplayer